# Simple question about calculating covariance with random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, covariance

Consider two random variables $X,Y$ with $X$ having values in ${2,3}$ and $Y$ in ${4,7}$, each with probability $0.5$. This then means that both random variables are equally distributed. Calculating the expected value gives $$E(X)=0.5(2+3)=2.5, \ E(Y)=0.5(4+7)=5.5.$$ The variance is easy to calulate as well. However when it comes to the covariance I seem to struggle because of the distribution. One knows that $(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))= 0.75$ with probability $P(X=2,Y=4)=?$. I know that when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we can just calculate $P(X=2,Y=4)=P(X=2)P(Y=4)=0.25$. However, can I also calculate a value here when they are not independent? Furthermore we have that $(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))=0.75$ with probability $P(X=3,Y=7)=?$. $$Cov(X,Y)=E((X-E(X)(Y-E(Y))=0.75(P(X=2,Y=4)+P(X=3,Y=7))=?.$$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If they are not independent, you need to know the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to calculate the covariance.

Comment: @Toni Thank you for your comment. If they were independent though, I would get $3/8$?

Comment: You should get 0 because independent random variables are uncorrelated. As a tip, it is usually easier to calculate $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$. If $X,Y$ are independent, then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ and hence $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$.

Comment: @Toni Thanks again for your comment. What you said makes sense to me, however I don't see why I dont get the result 0 in my example above. Could you give an example where the covariance is not zero but one can calculate everything?

Comment: See e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Example